# MySQL multiplication

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to do a multiplication operation in MySQL.
I have the following table called vehicul:

```
id car_type car_model  number price  car_id
1    audi    <model1>    2     320     1
2    audi    <model2>    4     100     1
3    bmw     <model1>    3     240     2
4    bmw     <model2>    6     500     2
5    bmw     <model3>    1     400     2
```

I have this command:

```
SELECT car_type, sum(price) FROM vehicul as v, GROUP BY marca
```

Which displays the following:

```
car_type  price 
audi       420  
bmw        1140
```

But what I want is to display the number * price and the result to be:

```
car_type  price 
audi       1040  
bmw        4120
```

Basically.. sum(number*price).. how can I do that? I have tried doing:

```
SELECT car_type, sum(price*number) FROM vehicul as v, GROUP BY marca
```

But I am getting:

```
#1052 - Column 'number' in field list is ambiguous
```

Comment: Try this `SELECT v.car_type, sum(v.price)*sum(v.number) as multiple FROM vehicul v, GROUP BY v.marca`

Comment: I believe you have added the "AS v" in the wrong place? Shouldn't it be after "sum(number)"?

Comment: select car_type, sum(price*number) as price from vehicul group by car_type.. post SQL Fiddle here

Comment: @ПавелИванов Same error as I got in the main post.

Comment: @ashin999 It is not working.

Comment: Are you _sure_ 2620 is the desired result for audi? Seems strange to add up all car prices and multiply by the total number of cars. The total value of the cars isn't SUM(a)*SUM(b), but SUM(a*b).

Comment: Maybe you just need to escape or put ticks on that "number" column. That is a risky name for a column... it could be misinterpreted.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson You are right. Fixed the main post.

Comment: @MrSilent http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d881/1

Comment: Fix it more. You still have sum()*sum() everywhere.

Comment: You don't have a column called marca. This question is gibberish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select car_type, sum(price*number) as price from vehicul group by car_type..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d881/1

you should use sum(field_1*field_2) instead of sum()*sum()

Answer (score 1):

Your query is totally correct. You may have more than 1 table which contain 2 or more number column. Try:

```
SELECT car_type, sum(price)*sum(number) 
FROM vehicul
GROUP BY marca;
```

But with the logic you will need this to get total price:

```
SELECT car_type, sum(price*number) 
FROM vehicul
GROUP BY marca;
```